# Quarkus / Restclient with proxy configuration

Tags: java, quarkus, microprofile, quarkus-rest-client

I am using quarkus 1.10.5.Final and need to call web service with web proxy.
Currently my code using microprofile client proxy and put below configuration in application.properties

```
client/mp-rest/url=https://remote.com
client/mp-rest/scope=javax.inject.Dependent
client/mp-rest/trustStore=classpath:/META-INF/resources/cacerts
client/mp-rest/connectTimeout=5000
client/mp-rest/readTimeout=5000
client/mp-rest/followRedirects=true
client/mp-rest/proxyAddress=http://proxy:8080
```

but still resulting  RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known

I tried to use -Dhttp.proxyHost and -Dhttp.proxyPort to test the proxy and it was success.
the problem is I can't use -Dparams since it will break other service calls.

this link where I got config for mp-rest/proxyAddress
https://download.eclipse.org/microprofile/microprofile-rest-client-2.0-RC2/microprofile-rest-client-2.0-RC2.html
but its not mentioned in https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.1.1.Final/userguide/html/MicroProfile_Rest_Client.html
please let me know if I am looking on wrong thing.

Answer (score 3):

### May 2021 update

Quarkus 2.0 supports MicroProfile Rest Client 2.0. With it you can use the configuration you mention, namely

```
# A string value in the form of <proxyHost>:<proxyPort> that specifies the
# HTTP proxy server hostname (or IP address) and port for requests of
# this client to use.
client/mp-rest/proxyAddress=host:port
```

Or set it programmatically with

```java
ProxiedClient client = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                                        .baseUri(someUri)
                                        .proxyAddress("myproxy.mycompany.com", 8080)
                                        .build(ProxiedClient.class);
```

### Original answer

You should be able to set proxy for your Quarkus Rest client with the following properties:

```
    org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.host
    org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.port
    org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.scheme
```

Answer (score 0):

I just run into the same problem and found this issue.

[Upgrade to MP Rest Client 2.0 #10520](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10520)

MP-Rest-Client 2.0 is not available in quarkus 1.10.5.

Comment: You're right, I will use HttpClient instead as workaround