# Quarkus rest client not respecting -Dhttp.proxyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort proxy options

Tags: java, http, proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, quarkus

I want to specify my Quarkus application (v2.8.3.Final) to use an HTTP proxy *without changing any code*

To attempt this I pass the `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort` options to the terminal, like this:

```
./mvnw quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0 -Dquarkus.http.port=9000 -Ddebug=9001 -Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=6969
```

- This *works* for other Java applications that are based on Jersey and Tomcat
- This *works* on another Quarkus application as well, (created at another point, but I have ensured that the Quarkus versions are the same, v2.8.3.Final in `pom.xml`)

##### Comparing the working quarkus app and the problematic one

To compare the working quarkus application (*A*), and the other (*B*) I have implemented a resource that sends a request to `http://google.com`

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

   .
   .
   .

    @GET
    @Path("/google")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String google() {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        return client.target("http://www.google.com")
                     .request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                     .get()
                     .readEntity(String.class);
    }
```

and I have ensured that the Quarkus versions are the same. Here is a *minimal* snippet from `pom.xml`

```
  <properties>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.8.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
  </properties>
```

Application *A* successfully passes its requests to the proxy server, while *B* wont. Both applications are very similiar when comparing their `pom.xml` files and `application.properties` files. I am struggling to point out relevant differences. I would like to at least get some pointers on where I could look to fix this problem.

##### Other things I have attempted in addition to passing `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort`:

- In application properties, specify

  - `org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.host=http://localhost`,
  - `org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.port=6969`
  - result: requests not going through proxy
  - source: [Quarkus / Restclient with proxy configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65686908/quarkus-restclient-with-proxy-configuration)
- In application properties, specify

  - `quarkus.rest-client.proxy-address=http://localhost:6969`,
  - result: requests not going through proxy
  - source: https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config
- In application properties specify `client/mp-rest/proxyAddress=http://localhost:6969`

  - result: request not going through proxy
- Other ways to pass the system properties `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort`

  - E.g. by setting the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dhttp.proxyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort"`
  - result: requests not going through proxy
- Built and started a docker container with Dockerfile.jvm generated from quarkus (which is included when create a new quarkus project), then setting the env variable `HTTP_PROXY=localhost:6969`.

  - It simply prints that it passes the `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort` options to the application (what I have done from the beginning)
  - result: requests not going through proxy

**System info**

- OS: Windows 11, but I do everything within WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS).
- CPU: Intel Core i7-10850H

Comment: Are you using the old REST client https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client or the new reactive one https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive (which mentions proxy support)?

Comment: @ewramner Great point, I am infact using the old rest client in the one that doesn't work, and the new rest client in the other. I will attempt to change the old one to use the reactive extensions instead.

Comment: @ewramner Thank you so much! I simply changed `quarkus-rest-client` to `quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson` in pom.xml and now the requests go through the proxy! If you rewrite your comment as an answer I can mark it as as correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarkus comes with two REST clients, the old [classic version](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client) and the newer [reactive one](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive). The reactive client has proxy support; the classic does not advertise it. Try to switch to the reactive client.

(copied from comment)